# Smarty in Prestashop parses as Javascript an Script tag even when the type is different

Tags: javascript, smarty, prestashop, handlebars.js

I'm trying to use Handlebars.js in Prestashop, currently the platform uses Smarty as is main FrontEnd Template Engine.

I have the following code:

```
{literal}
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="say-hello">
            Hi Everyone!
        </script>
{/literal}
```

The problem is that I get a Javascript  console problem, because `Hi Everyone!` can't be interpretated in Javascript, also I notice that Smarty places the `Hi Everyone!` inside an Script tag that doesn't respects the type nor the data-template-name attribute.